# javascript xhr load iframe in response

Tags: javascript, ajax, iframe, xmlhttprequest

Does anyone have an idea how to make this XHR request response load the .php file into an iframe as opposed to directly?

```
var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://example.com/foo/bar/baz.php', true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange= function() {
        if (this.readyState!==4) return;
        if (this.status!==200) return;
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML + this.responseText;    
};
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Why not just set the `src` of the iframe?

Comment: Modern browsers do not allow credentials to be passed to an <iframe> src attribute. This is a good workaround.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML + this.responseText;
```

with this:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.srcdoc = this.responseText;
iframe.src = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + escape(this.responseText);
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Alternatively, if you just want to display the page in an iFrame without making the XHR request. Just use this as your code:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = 'http://derrick.dk/ogmobi/facebook/contentLockerFacebook.php';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Comment: I was told that html response using XMLHttpRequest cannot be easily displayed in an iframe. It took me 2 hours and this post to prove it wrong.

Comment: I'm curious how this approach is affected by CORS and CSP.

Comment: @Dai The `data:text/html` option would require you to request from the same domain name or a CORS-whitelisted domain, and you'd need to have data URLs allowed by your CSP. The option for setting the src to the URL would require the URL of the iFrame to be allowed by the frame-src directive on the parent page, and the parent URL would need to be allowed by frame-ancestors.

Comment: Would the iframe inherit the same CSP rules as the parent page?

Comment: @Eric No, as a security feature to prevent the parent page from modifying the behavior of the page inside the iframe, the page inside the iframe is not subject the the CSP rules of the parent page, with the exception that the iframe page can only be loaded from URLs subject to the parent page's CSP. If you want to force a CSP on the embedded page, there's a draft "csp" attribute for iframes that allow you to make the page only load if its CSP is at least as strict as the one you include in the attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/csp